# Output when watching CoffeeScript files from a cakefile task

Tags: coffeescript

I would like to make a Cakefile task to watch some CoffeeScript files just like if I had run `coffee -c -w js/*.coffee`.

Its watching and recompiling them successfully, but it doesn't log the usual output to the terminal when there's a compile error like it would if I just ran the script from the terminal.  Any idea how to make this happen?

```
exec = require('child_process').exec

task 'watch','watch all files and compile them as needed', (options) ->
    exec 'coffee -c -w js/*.coffee', (err,stdout, stderr) ->
        console.log stdout
```

Also, if there's a better way to invoke a coffeescript command from a cakefile than running 'exec' please post that too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`spawn`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.6/api/child_processes.html#child_process.spawn) instead of `exec`?

```
{spawn} = require 'child_process'

task 'watch', -> spawn 'coffee', ['-cw', 'js'], customFds: [0..2]
```

Comment: `customFds` is deprecated: http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html. daniel's solution worked like a charm for me.

Comment: You can also use `stdio: 'inherit'` instead of `customFds: [0..2]`.

Answer (score 4):

I've used spawn to solve this, here is an example cake file:

```
{spawn, exec} = require 'child_process'

option '-p', '--prefix [DIR]', 'set the installation prefix for `cake install`'

task 'build', 'continually build with --watch', ->
    coffee = spawn 'coffee', ['-cw', '-o', 'lib', 'src']
    coffee.stdout.on 'data', (data) -> console.log data.toString().trim()
```

You can see it in action with the docco project:
https://github.com/jashkenas/docco/blob/master/Cakefile

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your original code was that `exec` only calls its callback once—after the child process has terminated. (The Node docs aren't so clear on this.) So instead of defining that callback, you should instead try

```
child = exec 'coffee -c -w js/*.coffee'
child.stdout.on 'data', (data) -> sys.print data
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: `sys` wasn't defined and I used console.log instead of print: ```child.stdout.on 'data', (data) -> console.log data```